# Python: How to read file and store certain columns in array

Tags: python, arrays, list, file, io

I am reading a dataset (separated by whitespace) from a file. I need to store all columns apart from last one in the array `data`, and the last column in the array `target`.

Can you guide me how to proceed further?

That's what I have so far:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

Or should I be reading line by line?

PS: The data type of columns is also different.

**Edit:** Sample Data

```
faban       1   0   0.288   withspy
faban       2   0   0.243   withoutspy
simulated   1   0   0.159   withoutspy
faban       1   1   0.189   withoutspy
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample data?

Comment: Kindly check edit part.

Comment: You probably want to use the csv module.

Comment: Please describe the output as well

Comment: If you're going to do some sort of analysis later, you can probably also look at pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/). It provides functionality to read in data from CSV files. You can then separate the columns and play around with the data in the way you wish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would work:

```
data = []
target = []
with open('faban.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        row = line.split()
        data.append(row[:-1])
        target.append(row[-1])
```

Now:

```
>>> data
[['faban', '1', '0', '0.288'],
 ['faban', '2', '0', '0.243'],
 ['simulated', '1', '0', '0.159'],
 ['faban', '1', '1', '0.189']]

>>> target
['withspy', 'withoutspy', 'withoutspy', 'withoutspy']
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `numpy` has a clean, easy solution here.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data, target = np.array_split(np.loadtxt('file', dtype=str), [-1], axis=1)
```

results in:

```
>>> data.tolist()
[['faban', '1', '0', '0.288'], 
 ['faban', '2', '0', '0.243'], 
 ['simulated', '1', '0', '0.159'], 
 ['faban', '1', '1', '0.189']]
>>> target.flatten().tolist()
['withspy', 'withoutspy', 'withoutspy', 'withoutspy']
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do that with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) using [`read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) to read your data, [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to subset your data, [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) to get values from DataFrame and [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) method to convert numpy array to list:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('path_to_your_file', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
print(df)
           0  1  2      3           4
0      faban  1  0  0.288     withspy
1      faban  2  0  0.243  withoutspy
2  simulated  1  0  0.159  withoutspy
3      faban  1  1  0.189  withoutspy


data = df.iloc[:,:-1].values.tolist()
target = df.iloc[:,-1].tolist()

print(data)
[['faban', 1, 0, 0.28800000000000003],
 ['faban', 2, 0, 0.243],
 ['simulated', 1, 0, 0.159],
 ['faban', 1, 1, 0.18899999999999997]]

print(target)
['withspy', 'withoutspy', 'withoutspy', 'withoutspy']
```

Comment: `read_table` is deprecated, modern version : `pd.read_csv('path_to_your_file', sep='\t', header=None)`.  As a bonus note that you can name columns with `names=['foo','bar','whatever','target']`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works nicely:

```
data = open('<FILE>', 'r').read().split('\n')
out = []
for l in data:
    out.append([e for e in l.split(' ') if e])
```

**out** will then have the the format *[['faban', '1', '0', '0.288', 'withspy'],[...],...]* (Note, all elements are strings)